# How to change all elements except clicked element?

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, click

I'm working on a world map visualization using Javascript and D3.js. When you click on a country all other countries get a class `inactiveCountry` which adds a `opacity: 0.3`, which highlights the selected country. What I would like is that when you click the highlighted country again, all other countries lose the class `inactiveCountry` so they have a `opacity: 1` again.

This is the map:
[image]

When selecting a country:
[image]

The following is the code that draws and colors the map:

```js
        g.selectAll("path").data(countries.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", pathGenerator)
            .attr("class", "country")
            .attr("id", function (d){
                return d.properties.name
            })
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return colorScaleWorldmap(colorValue(d))
            })
            .on("click", function (d) {
                changeCountry(d.properties.name);
            })
            .append("title")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.properties.name + ": " + colorValue(d);
            });
```

As you can see, when you click on a country it runs the function `changeCountry();`, which is this:

```js
function changeCountry(countryName) {

    country = countryName;
    console.log(country);

    let totalCountries = document.getElementsByClassName("country");

    // Remove class countryActive from previous selection
    for (let i = 0; i < totalCountries.length; i++) {
        if (totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryActive")) {
            totalCountries[i].classList.replace("countryActive", "countryInactive")
        }
    }

    // Add class countryActive to selected country
    let element = document.getElementById(country);
    element.classList.add("countryActive");

    for (let i = 0; i < totalCountries.length; i++) {
        if (totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryActive")) {
            totalCountries[i].classList.remove("countryInactive")
        } else {
            totalCountries[i].classList.add("countryInactive")
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding an interaction where when you click the selected country *again*, all countries become visible (thus losing the class `countryInactive`)? I've tried using a JQuery `.click` and `.data` combination as such:

```js
    $("#" + country).click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });

    if($("#" + country).data('clicked')) {
        alert('yes');
    }
```

The problem with this piece of code is that once I've clicked a country at least once, it seems to keep the `true` statement, so even when I click it while it's inactive, I get the `yes` alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function changeCountry(countryName) {

    let clickedContry = document.getElementById(countryName);
    let totalCountries = document.getElementsByClassName("country");

    if(clickedContry.classList.contains("countryActive")) {
        for (let i = 0; i < totalCountries.length; i++) {
            if (totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryInactive")) {
                totalCountries[i].classList.replace("countryInactive", "countryActive");
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Remove class countryActive from previous selection
        clickedContry.classList.add("countryActive");
    }
}
```

.

But remember.. you still didn't think about what will happen when you have a clicked country and the user click in another.

Good Luck!

Comment: While your solution didn't fix it for me completely, your answer was a big help in solving my problem. I answered this question with my own answer if you're interested in seeing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the solution [thiagotrss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562675/thiagotrss) provided I managed to solve it myself. This is how I did it:

```js
function changeCountry(countryName) {

    let totalCountries = document.getElementsByClassName("country");
    let clickedCountry = document.getElementById(countryName);
    country = countryName;
    console.log(country);

    if (clickedCountry.classList.contains("countryActive")) {
        clickedCountry.classList.remove("countryActive")
        country = "Total countries";

        for (let i = 0; i < totalCountries.length; i++) {
            if (totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryInactive")) {
                totalCountries[i].classList.remove("countryActive")
                totalCountries[i].classList.remove("countryInactive")
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < totalCountries.length; i++) {
            if (totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryActive")) {
                totalCountries[i].classList.remove("countryActive")
            } else if (!totalCountries[i].classList.contains("countryActive")) {
                totalCountries[i].classList.add("countryInactive")
            }
        }
        clickedCountry.classList.add("countryActive")
    }
}
```